# Dynamically add column to html table in react

Tags: reactjs, html-table, react-redux

what should i do to display data vertically in column in react js or any components from library in reactjs or raw javascript? Like this [compare product table](https://compass.alibaba.com/detail/compareProducts.html?ids=50035473359,50015761666,119353524,50035045166,60563352676,1661678724&pids=) in alibaba.

Let's say we have this table

```
  <table id="vertical-1">
        <caption>First Way</caption>
        <tr>
            <th>Product Name</th>
            <th>Product 1</th><th>Product 2</th><th>Product 3</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Image</th>
            <td>Image 1</td><td>Image 2</td><td>Image 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Price</th>
            <td>300</td><td>500</td><td>800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Size</th>
            <td>S, M, L</td><td>S, XL</td><td>XL, L</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

and this source

```
dataSource = [{
id: '1',
name: 'Product 1',
image: 'Image 1',
price: '300',
size: 'S, M, XL, L'
}, {
id: '2',
name: 'Product 2',
image: 'Image 2',
price: '500',
size: 'S, XL'
}, {
id: '3',
name: 'Product 3',
image: 'Image 3',
price: '800',
size: 'XL, L'}];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add column dynamically to a table my iterating through the data list using map method of javascript.Let dataSource be a state

```
<table id="vertical-1">
          <thead>
               <tr>
                   <th>Name</th>
                   <th>Image</th>
                   <th>Price</th>
                   <th>Size</th>
               </tr>
           <tbody>                                
            {this.state.dataSource.map((data, i) =>
               <tr key={i}>
               <td>data.name</td>
               <td><img src={data.image}/></td>
               <td>data.price</td>
               <td>data.size</td>
               </tr>

           )}
           </tbody>
          </thead>
</table>
```